# Minecraft Plugin spigot import com.earth2me.essentials?

Tags: java, build.gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge, spigot

Hello I am making a plugine with spigot api and I wanted to make a possible action according to the economy of the player (economy of essentials plugin). But I don't understand how I can add in dependency the essentials plugin on the build.gradle....

I hope someone can help me, It's been 5 days I'm blocked.

[class java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRrHn.png)
[Build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB1xe.png)

I hope to find a solution I don't know how to do...

Comment: share your code in plain text format!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error said, you should add import to essentials. The import should be what you added with `com.earth2me.essentials`, but it also should be the repository where the dependency is.

For this, you add this into your `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.essentialsx.net/releases/"
        name "Essentials releases"
    }
}
```

If you want snapshot (which is not your case here), you should add this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://repo.essentialsx.net/snapshots/"
        name "Essentials releases"
    }
}
```

[Documentation](https://essentialsx.net/wiki/Common-Issues.html)

Comment: With pleasure @EvanPerez :) Note: I suggest you to update your question with plain text instead of picture